# Run time error 1004 placing formula in cell

Tags: vba

I have created a formula that works in a spreadsheet but not in VBA.  What I have pasted here is only a subset of the entire formula; in total it exceeds 3,000 characters

If I run this, it works

```
LastRow = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("cI2:cI" & LastRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(MID(""00"",1,2-LEN(A2)),A2))"
```

If I run this, I get the run time error

```
LastRow = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("cI2:cI" & LastRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(MID(""00"",1,2-LEN(A2)),A2)), " & _
"CONCATENATE(MID(""00000000"",1,8-LEN(B2)),B2),""    "", CONCATENATE(C2,MID(""            "",1,12-LEN(C2))),CONCATENATE(MID(""00"",1,2-LEN(D2)),D2) "
```

Comment: It's probably due to the wrong use of `"`, which is also the delimiter of strings in VBA. If you want to write this: `"=IF(A1="test",True,False)"` in VBA, write it like `"=IF(A1=" + chr(34) + "test" + chr(34) + ",True,False)"` so you make sure you don't get this kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of the formula, I would suspect that it exceeds some of the internal limits Excel has for function. Possibilities that come to mind are:

> Arguments in a function: 255
>
> Nested levels of functions: 64
>
> Length of formula contents: 8,192 characters

You can find more information on the Office support page [here](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

That said, I'm curious why you would need to build a 3000 character formula to place in the cell.  This is what VBA is for - converting the formula into a user defined function is likely going to be the solution.